# Objective-C What way of multiple conditions are right?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a condition like this

```
if(hour == TT_MB_HOUR && minutes >= 0 && minutes <= TT_MB_MINUTES_END){
    return YES;
}
```

But I've seen somebody write like this

```
if((hour == TT_MB_HOUR) && (minutes >= 0) && (minutes <= TT_MB_MINUTES_END)){
    return YES;
}
```

So, What way is right?

Comment: Stick with the upper one. You can sometimes add braces for clarity, but in this case it would be similar to write something like: `if ((true) && (true))` (not exactly equivalent but I'll hope you get it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, What way is right?

Both of them.

As in most programming languages (Objective-)C uses *operator precedence* to determine in what order to evaluate operators within an expression. Just in the same way you know that `3 + 4 * 5` evaluates to `23` (and not to `35`) in maths.

The logical operators `&&` and `||` are lower priority than the comparison operators so are performed after them.

If is it unclear in any situation a good rule of thumb is "when there might be doubt add parentheses" to make explicit what is implicit (and of course if you need to change the priority as in `(3 + 4) * 5` which does evaluate to `35`). The author of your code obviously felt the parentheses made it clearer, they are neither right or wrong - its an opinion.

[Havard have a nice table](https://cs50.harvard.edu/resources/cppreference.com/operator_precedence.html) of C operator precedence.

HTH

Answer (score 4):

They both do the same thing if I'm seeing this right. I would put a line break after each &&, just for legibility

```
if (hour == TT_MB_HOUR &&
    minutes >= 0 && 
    minutes <= TT_MB_MINUTES_END) {
       return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Grouping boolean statements in the example above doesn't affect the outcome, however it becomes important when you combine `&&` with `||` statements